# Python Program - Use a while loop to calculate the amount of letter grades from user input

Tags: python

**I wrote some code for the following problem:**

*"Write a program to continuously asks the user an exam score given as integer percentages in the range 0 to 100. Calculate the total number of grades in each letter-grade category as follows: 90 to 100 is an A, 80 to 89 is a B, 70 to 79 is a C, 60 to 69 is a D, and 0 to 59 is an F. Use a negative score as a sentinel value to indicate the end of the input. (The negative value is used only to end the loop, so do not use it in the calculations.)"*

**Here is my code:**

```
count = 0
gradeA = 0
gradeB = 0
gradeC = 0
gradeD = 0
gradeF = 0

score = int(input("Enter an exam score: "))
while score != -1:
    count = count + 1
    score = int(input("Enter an exam score: "))

if score >= 90 and score <= 100:
    gradeA = gradeA + 1
elif score >= 80 and score <= 89:
    gradeB = gradeB + 1
elif score >= 70 and score <= 79:
    gradeC = gradeC + 1
elif score >= 60 and score <= 69:
    gradeD = gradeD + 1
elif score >= 0 and score <= 59:
    gradeF = gradeF + 1

print ("You entered " + str(count) + " exam scores.")
print ("Number of A's = " + str(gradeA))
print ("Number of B's = " + str(gradeB))
print ("Number of C's = " + str(gradeC))
print ("Number of D's = " + str(gradeD))
print ("Number of F's = " + str(gradeF))
```

**The issue is that when I run the code, the number of grades in each letter-grade category are all showing up as 0.
How could I fix this so that the correct numbers are shown?**

Comment: Shouldn't your `if` statements be in the body of the `while` loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to indent your if statements.

```
count = 0
gradeA = 0
gradeB = 0
gradeC = 0
gradeD = 0
gradeF = 0

score = int(input("Enter an exam score: "))
while score != -1:
    count = count + 1
    score = int(input("Enter an exam score: "))

    if score >= 90 and score <= 100:
        gradeA = gradeA + 1
    elif score >= 80 and score <= 89:
        gradeB = gradeB + 1
    elif score >= 70 and score <= 79:
        gradeC = gradeC + 1
    elif score >= 60 and score <= 69:
        gradeD = gradeD + 1
    elif score >= 0 and score <= 59:
        gradeF = gradeF + 1

print ("You entered " + str(count) + " exam scores.")
print ("Number of A's = " + str(gradeA))
print ("Number of B's = " + str(gradeB))
print ("Number of C's = " + str(gradeC))
print ("Number of D's = " + str(gradeD))
print ("Number of F's = " + str(gradeF))
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the if/elif statements arent included in the while loop so the variables arent actually getting updated. Try indenting that block so its inside the loop and see if that works!